# How Do I get proper error messages from Spring Security UI?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have been using spring security UI and spring security plugin. We have our register.gsp page which works as expected. We are moving our css to twitter bootstrap so we changed register.gsp file, to match our requriements.

So we changed :

```
<s2ui:textFieldRow name='username' labelCode='user.username.label' bean="${command}"
                         size='40' labelCodeDefault='Username' value="${command.username}"/>
```

To :

```
<g:textField class="input-large" bean="${command}" name="username"  
                               value = "${command.username}" required = "" />
```

Now the problem is how I render error messages? I get only default error message as now :

```
 Property {0} ... doesn't pass custom validation.
```

Actually I need to get the error message of what Spring Security UI offered. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok @batman, what about this question? Do you get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use:

```
<g:textField class="input-large" bean="${command}" name="username"  
                           value = "${command.username}" required = "" />
<g:eachError bean="${command}">
    <span>${it}</span>
</g:eachError>
```